# Copy of original Stack Exchange post hosted elsewhere

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

Is there any restriction or policy which guides about copying content from Stack Exchange?

I found a site which copied a question asked by me with all of the answers as it is with no reference to original post on Stack Exchange. Below are the links -

[Duplicate content](https://itectec.com/database/mariadb-how-to-limit-impact-of-a-bad-application-on-mariadb-galera-cluster-with-maxscale/)

[Original Stack Exchange post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/286204/how-to-limit-impact-of-a-bad-application-on-mariadb-galera-cluster-with-maxscale)